# Error while deploying the report The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]'

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions, reportserver

While I am trying to deploy the report it is giving the following error.

The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' 
contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) 
in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue).
Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.

But when I ran the report it is working fine. Only it is throwing error while deploying..

I used the following expression.

```
=IIF(Inscope("Group3")
,SUM(Fields!Prin_Bal.Value)
,SUM(IIF(Fields!Data_Dt.Value=Max(Fields!Data_Dt.Value)
,Fields!Prin_Bal.Value,0))
/SUM(IIF(Fields!Data_Dt.Value=
DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("q",1,DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m",-3,Max(Fields!Data_Dt.Value)))
, (3*DatePart("q",DateAdd("m",-3,Max(Fields!Data_Dt.Value))))-2
, 1))),Fields!Prin_Bal.Value,0))-1)))
```

I used SUM in nested loop. When I run the report it works fine with the correct values. Only it is thorowing error while deploying. Is there anything to do with version?

Could you please help on this?

Appreciate all and any help.

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: That expression is quite hard to read...  You may want to consider breaking some of the `Iif`s into separate calculated fields.

Comment: Basically it is because I am using nested IIf in aggregate function.SUM(IIF(Fields!Data_Dt.Value=Max(Fields!Data_Dt.Value)
,Fields!Prin_Bal.Value,0). I tried using calculated field but it didn't work out.